# SSH: Несколько туннелей на один порт

Tags: ssh, tunnel

Доброго дня. Задача заключается в следующем - есть сервер с белым IP на котором крутиться ssh-server, например под названием server.net, на нем открыт единственный порт, например 10030, как организовать возможность пробрасывать реверсивные туннели с нескольких клиентов на этот единственный порт. С одним клиентом проблем нет " ssh -f -N -R 10030:localhost:80 user@server.net ", а вот если два клиента, то ssh информирует, что порт занят и не дает открыть туннель. 
Вопрос как избежать данного ограничения, есть ли вообще такие способы?

Comment: А какого эффекта Вы хотите достичь. Вы пробрасываете порт сервера на клиента. Т.е. после этой операции когда кто-либо коннектится на порт 10030 сервера то его трафик по туннелю перебрасывается на клиента на порт 80. Предположим, что вам удалось сделать так как вы делаете и второй клиент подключил туннель. Тогда в случае коннекта на порт 10030 сервера какому из 2х клиентов он должен передать это соединение ?

Comment: Наоборот, я пробрасываю 80 порт клиента на 10030 порт сервера. Когда кто-то заходит на сервер по порту 10030, он получает трафик с 80 порта клиента, то есть подключается к локальному серверу, который развернут на клиенте. Задача разделения трафика от нескольких клиентов, тоже пока не решена, я иду step by step. Вкратце, цель в следующем, есть клиенты (на них крутятся сервера), есть один сервер, который должен предоставить доступ к серверу клиента удалённо. Проблема заключается в том, что сервера на клиентах локальные,то есть в большинстве случаем не имеют белых IP и скрыты за роутером.

Comment: Ну что куда пробрасывается, думаю просто в терминологии расходимся :) Важно другое, вы говорите "Когда кто-то заходит на сервер по порту 10030, он получает трафик с 80 порта клиента". И тут же встает вопрос, с 80 порта какого клиента он должен получить трафик, как ssh висящей на 10030 понять, кому отдавать трафик ? Собственно т.к. ssh просто тупой туннель и она не может понимать по содержимому трафика куда его отдавать она и требует под каждого клиента отдельный порт, что бы это понимать ... Как конечный пользователь подключающийся к 10030 задает какой клиент ему нужен ?

Comment: Я не претендую на лучшее решение, если есть другие пути я готов выслушать :) Идея в том, чтобы перенаправить трафик каждого клиента на поддомены и уже конечного пользователя отправлять на поддомен

Comment: Вот, отлично. Значит там обычный http и по разным машинам (клиентам) они должны ходить по _имени домена_ они в браузере пишут `имя.поддомена:10030` ? (ну как вы задумывали)

Comment: Нет, они пишут домен, а сервер сам перенаправляет на поддомен, но думаю это не так принципиально :)

Comment: Я правда не понял, почему тогда порт не 80. В общем ответ который ниже дали верный. Вам надо что-бы "клиенты" делали туннели на разные порты, за каждым клиентом закрепить свой порт. А на _главном порту_ который указывают в браузерах пользователи (хотя все таки 80 лучше, чем 10030) что бы висел nginx и по домену делал проксирование на тот или иной порт localhost

Comment: Нет, данное решение мне не подходит к сожалению.

Comment: У вас там какие то жесткие ограничения по портам ?

Comment: Я так понимаю, раз ограничение такое жесткое, то софт организующий полноценные VPN тоннели вам то же не подходит, ибо он требует рута и использует помимо портов tcp зачастую другие протоколы уровня IP. То что вы хотите - это web-прокси с возможностью самой удерживать туннели до серверов. На столько не специфичная задача, что боюсь готового софта под нее нет. надо свою проксю делать

Comment: Нет, ограничение не такие жесткие, как в приведенном примере, но на сервере помимо нас еще есть другие клиенты, то есть по портам особо не разгуляешься. Можно попробовать договориться, чтобы нам пару портов выделили на постоянное пользование, но это задачу не решит, так как клиентов может быть много.

Comment: А рута Вам дадут и возможность создавать свои интерфейсы в системе ? Если да, то openvpn и маршрутизация виртуальной сеточки по полной программе. Еще идея пришла. А вам на локальном интерфейсе этой машины могут поднять еще один ip, скажем 127.0.0.2, Если да - то цепляете свои ssh туннели на порты этого ip, а на основной порт nginx. Хотя если другие порты в системе используются в режиме "все ip" то может не прокатить. тогда набор ip из 127 подсети на локальном интерфейсе ...

Comment: Нет, конечно рута мне никто не даст. Можно конечно подумать в сторону своего сервера, но известно как к таким переменам относятся начальники :) Данная идея, вообще, возникла не с проста, а так как она уже реализована, а люди которые это реализовали не хотят делится. Клиенты стучаться только на один порт, а сервер клиентов нормально разделяет. А у меня пока не вышло юзать один порт, хотя я знаю что это возможно.

Comment: Ага, и отсюда такая политика с портами, хотят что бы их юзали ... Если все коннектятся на 1 порт, то где остальные 65534 порта ? А если схема работает, вы не можете узнать чем коннектятся те клиенты (ну кроме тех, которые браузеры) ?

Comment: Увы, все настройки спрятаны на сервере и вот все что мне известно: 
1 - Для создания туннеля используется только один сервер-порт на всех клиентах. При создании туннеля по средствам ssh на сервер отсылается приватный ключ и логин с паролем от клиента
2 - Конечный юзер заходит на их ресурс и вводит логин и пароль, который совпадает с тем который отослали
3 - Юзер попадает на локальный сервер, который крутится на клиенте.

Comment: Я подобного не встречал и мне кажется это что то самописное. А вы хотите реализовать что то подобное, только с обращением не по логину-паролю, а по доменному имени.

Comment: Нет, я хочу организовать именно как они, а по поводу доменов, это чисто моя идея распределения клиентов на сервере. Т.е. юзер вводит логин и пасс, а сервер его редиректом на временный поддомен

Comment: Я тут вот нашел https://ngrok.com/docs/2#tcp-examples   Я не знаю что это и применимо ли оно, но экзамплы из документации меня заинтриговали.

Comment: Я уже смотрел в сторону ngrok, localtunnel и ему подобных. Они мне не подходят так как зависимость от их ресурсов не уместна. ngrok позволяет юзать свои серваки, но и у него ограничения 1 клиент под одним ip, а в моем случаи у одного юзера может быть несколько клиентов. 
И да, спасибо, что пытаетесь мне активно помочь :)

Comment: Боюсь придется писать что то свое, либо надо искать хакеров, у них подобный софт должен быть из разряда ботнетов :)

Comment: Да @Mike , видимо придется писать, что-то свое. А по поводу хакеров, если к ним обращаться, то проще попросить чтоб сервер хакнули, где лежит ответ на мой вопрос =)

Answer (score 1):

если, как выяснилось в дискуссии, вам требуется «разводить в разные стороны» *http-трафик*, то логичнее использовать какой-нибудь *http-proxy-сервер* (например, *nginx*).

который, в зависимости от *http-заголовка* `host:`, будет перенаправлять *http-запрос* клиента на указанный вами компьютер.

клиенты со своими *http-серверами* могут пробрасывать туннели на уникальные локальные порты сервера. а nginx будет на эти локальные порты проксировать соединения.

ориентировочный пример конфигурации *nginx* для домена *domain.name* и локального порта 2001:

```
server {
  server_name domain.name;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2001;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Я боюсь там проблема чуть сложнее, их сервера походу не имеют собственных реальных ip и их потом собирают на проксирующий сервер. Но ваша ссылка пригодится, потому как настроек nginx я например не знал, а он по любому понадобится. Хотя там что то про поддомены говорили, может понадобится проксирование по именам доменов

Comment: клиенты могут пробрасывать туннели на уникальные локальные порты сервера. а nginx будет на эти локальные порты проксировать соединения. *может понадобится проксирование по именам доменов* — по dns-именам *http-proxy* обычно и различают подключения, и «срабатывает» та или иная секция в конфигурации.

Comment: Да, именно это я имел ввиду под "чуть сложнее". Просто в той статье идет редирект по location, подразумевается ли в нем и имя домена ? Если да - то никаких проблем, если сейчас не выяснится что по каким то чудовищным условиям задачи они не могут использовать более 1 порта. Просто я бы понял эту схему если бы они 80 порт использовали, что бы пользователям не надо было порт хоть указывать...

Comment: это просто была первая попавшаяся ссылка на сайте, где упоминается директива *proxy_pass*. лишь для иллюстрации. конечно, конфигурация в данном случае будет иной. о чём лучше спросить отдельным вопросом.

Comment: Я уже смотрел в сторону nginx, перед тем как задать вопрос здесь, я перелопатил кучу информации и не нашел решения своей задачи. Как я писал раньше доступен, только один порт, не считая стандартных. Если бы я мог использовать набор различных портов проблем бы не возникло. На клиентах бы пробрасывался порт, а сервер бы просто направлял на данный уникальный порт и все.

Comment: Задача не так проста. Даже если предположить, что на сервере нет ограничений, то все равно встают проблемы, когда число клиентов возрастёт. Во-первых количество портов ограничено протоколом. Во-вторых можно попасть на занятые порты.

Comment: @Артем, вам нужно пробросить несколько туннелей от клиентов на сервер. на сервере достаточно одного *внешнего* порта, который будет слушать sshd (обычно — 22-й). каждый клиент создаёт туннель, привязанный к *внутреннему* порту на сервере. их может быть *много*.

Comment: @alexander barakin, можете подробнее описать идею, а то не очень ясно что Вы предлагаете?

Comment: @Артем, я не знаю, как *ещё* подробнее описать. спрашивайте, что именно вам непонятно.

Comment: Мозг с утра еще плохо соображает :), порт который слушает ssh (тот который по умолчанию 22) служат для соединения ssh-клиентов к ssh-серверу и не как не может мне помочь. Если конечно @alexander barakin, вы не имели ввиду что-то иное.